# Amount of money needed to apply for a B1/B2 US visa in Russia?

Tags: usa, money, scams

I have a friend that wants to come and spend some time with me in the U.S. from Russia. She has told me that in order to get her visa approved she has to show that she financial means while here with me. The amount is 1800$ that she is supposed to show the Travel agent and if she can't show that amount she will be denied for out of country travel for the period of 5 years. How much is fact or is all fiction?

Comment: When you say 'friend' do you mean someone you have known personally for a long time, or someone you met online?

Comment: Single female visiting a single male she may be denied on those grounds.  I don't know where $1800 came from and I wouldn't trust any agent until she applies for a visa.

Comment: It's the full on signature of a scam, beware. However, your gf may be innocently echoing what the agent told her. A lot of them don't have any visa experience so don't dump her just yet. :)   When I was in practice I arranged hundreds of visitor visas for Russian girls (albeit for the UK) and ran into this all the time. Use your own b1 attorney stateside and you'll be thankful for having done it.

Comment: Everybody has to show financial means to get a visa. Everything else is fiction. The number came out of someone's back side, and the travel ban is false as well.

Comment: Is this the point at which she asks if you can pay her the $1800 and then disappears? The claim about a travel ban makes no sense at all: whether or not she gets a U.S. visa is purely a matter between her and the U.S. Department of State. The Russian government wouldn't even know she'd applied.

Comment: Note that the question above is not a duplicate in *content*, but it's a duplicate in *spirit*, since it's asking about a Russian "woman" asking for money for travel-related purposes.